# Maven Dependency with Parent Pom Not Working Properly

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have the following maven structure.

**Parent Pom**

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**Service Pom**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.aliseeks.dependencies</groupId>
    <artifactId>AliseeksLive</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Dependency Conflict:**

```
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.25.1:compile
```

Why does Maven pull in `JerseyCommon 2.25`? `JerseyClient 2.27` clearly depends on `JerseyCommon 2.25`? Is this because `JerseyClient 2.27` POM has `${project.version}` as a variable and its somehow getting messed up with Dependency Management?

[Dependency Tree Dump](https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.waka.run/deptree.txt)

Comment: As per http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.27/jersey-client-2.27.pom, there is another dep org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2 which also uses project.version. Check that jar's version too that might give you some hint - possibly

Comment: It's also getting pulled in as 2.25 .

Comment: OK. In that case, 'mvn dependency:tree > deptree.txt' command is the final frontier. This should create deptree.txt file and list all the deps in it. Find jersey-common:jar file if it exists anywhere other than jersey-client. If that does then you have to exclude it from that dep but if it doesn't then project.version is 2.25.1.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to dump all the properties? I mean project.version is resolved in the context of the JerseyClient POM isn't it? So the JerseyClient POM project.version would have to be 2.27? I did a dependency tree dump, let me add that here.

Comment: Heres the dependency tree dump https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.waka.run/deptree.txt

Comment: Jesus dude, I figured it out. I was importing the Spring Boot BOM POM and it had jersey.version set to 2.25 so I was setting JerseyClient to 2.27 but the Spring Boot BOM had all the other dependencies managed to 2.25

Comment: As I see source code, `core-client:2.27` use `jersey-common:2.27` https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.27/core-client/pom.xml#L128

Answer (score 0):

jersey-client 2.27 version depends on jersey-common 2.27 version as per following link:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.27

But it is definitely pulling 2.25 version of jersey-common after resolving transitive dependencies and maven finds 2.25 version as the nearest child. That's reason it decides to pull 2.25 version.

For the reference that such type of dependency conflict issues can be easily investigated with the help of `maven-enforcer-plugin`. Following link further explains usage of this plugin with example:

https://dzone.com/articles/solving-dependency-conflicts-in-maven